# How to detect RTP packets in a PCAP file?

Tags: network-programming, analytics, voip, wireshark, rtp

I have a `.pcap` file captured from my network adapter using Wireshark. I'm trying to analyses its contents using a python script. The problem is that I can't find anything specific to RTP packets in the Wireshark. Note that I don't want to use the port numbers to detect the protocol. I want to inspect the raw data and detect the RTP protocol packets. Is there any way to do that? I mean is there anything special in RTP packets that I can use that statistic to detect RTP packets among a lot of other protocols packets?

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark analyses the VOIP signaling messages to know which UPD ports are being used for RTP. Apart from the version number bits (and thats really too short), the RTP packets themselves don't have much you can use to identify them by themselves.

Comment: Does all the packets of a single session have equal `PT` and equal `PX`? Do you have any reference for your claim about the Wireshark policy?

Comment: I looked at the source code for the H.323 dissector in Wireshark and why it doesn't mark the RTP packets when H.460.19 is used. Wireshark may be able to detect RTP when standard port numbers are used, not sure.

Comment: Whether wireshark displays RTP or not has nothing to do with H.460.19.
Also RTP doesn’t have any standard port.

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in wireshark that allows RTP detection without signaling:
Edit menu -> Preferences -> Protocols -> RTP -> Allow subdissector to reassemble RTP streams

Comment: How does the Wireshark detect RTP packets without signaling packets?